# vim and its latex plugin: compilation optimization

Tags: vim, vim-latex

At the moment, using vim I have to first save with `:w` and then compile using `\ll`, moreover compilation displays all sort of trash and asks to press `enter` at the end; what I would like instead is that when I press `\ll` it automatically saves and displays only something similar to when I digit in my terminal `pdflatex file | grep arning`: is it possible to achieve this with something like `let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex $* | grep arnin` in my `.vimrc` file?

Comment: This sounds like a pretty bad plugin! I  would remove it instantly and install a plugin like https://github.com/lervag/vimtex instead! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf` is used as part of the compilation process, vim-latex has some capabilities to repeat compilations until the entire document is compiled (i.e. `\ll` will trigger a `latex bibtex latex latex` run if appropriate based on detected changes to the `aux` etc. files) so that shouldn't be doing more than executing whichever flavour of LaTeX you're using with the appropriate options.

In order to save and compile the file I introduce a new mapping,

```
map <Leader>t :w<CR><bar><Leader>ll
```

in my `.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` file (which I use such that this mapping will only be enabled for files with filetype `tex` rather than for all files as you'd get using your `.vimrc`).  From this whenever I use `\t` vim will first write the file then execute the default vim-latex compile that you get from `\ll`.

I'm not clear what the aim of `grep arning` (`warning`?) is, but as with the case above you should be able to use

```
map <Leader>t :w<CR><bar><Leader>ll<bar>:grep arning *<CR>
```

or whatever you would do in vim to achieve the desired effect after the second .

Comment: thanks! yes, actually i do grep Warning and overfull

Comment: actually, with let g:tex_flavor = "latex" and let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf' in my .vimrc i still do not get the output as parsed by grep, and moreover it does not save even with your suggestion. i think i'm misunderstanding something here

Comment: just to clarify, the meaning of grep arning is to obtain the same as when i type in the shell pdflatex file.tex | grep Warning, but this is of secondary relevance wrt the save issue

Comment: perhaps a confusion is that i don't have a tex.vim in ftplugin, instead i have latex-suite; does it work the same way? if so, where should i put the above line?

Comment: @jj_p I'm suggesting define a new mapping (`\t`) which does "save and compile" here, rather than modifying the old one, otherwise if you reload the `.vimrc` you should see the desired effect.  As far as grepping, `:grep warning<CR>` will call vim's grep, for the command line you want `:!grep warning<CR>` as I understand.

Comment: Using `.vimrc` and the `.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` are equivalent, the latter is only loaded for one filetype so stuff is only executed when necessary, while `.vimrc` applies the remapping to all filetypes.  You could create such a located `tex.vim` file, but if you're happy with the remapping being placed globally there's no need.

Comment: and indeed it works as you say

Comment: however the grep thing is still not doing anything with grep, and just  blocking with !grep. what i want to grep are warnings during pdflatex compile time

Comment: I still think that what I have in mind could be achieved by something like let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = "pdflatex | grep arning" in my .vimrc but I'm still missing some details..

Comment: Ah, try `map <Leader>t :w<CR><bar><Leader>ll<bar>:grep warning *<CR>` which will use grep from within vim.  Vim-LaTeX does open a split containing excerpts from the log with any warnings should they occur which can be somewhat customised (http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/compiler-output-customization.html)

Comment: one last thing that i cannot figure out: how do i navigate and leave the enviroment produced by grep, provided i have the line set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $* in my .vimrc?

Comment: @jj_p I have no experience of grep (hence didn't twig the need for a wildcard), if you don't want the vim grep, use`:!grep` rather than `:grep`, otherwise I can't really help, it sounds like this is now a grep/vim-specific problem.

Comment: Right now I'm using :!grep 'Warning' but if I try something more elaborate like :!grep 'Warning\|Overful' it does not seem to work, while it works in the shell; here it just returns 1: is there a way to fix it?